# How to get milliseconds after midnight with the hours, minutes and seconds we give in the function? (in Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, milliseconds

How to get milliseconds after midnight with the hours, minutes and seconds we give in the function? (in Python)

```
def past(h,m,s):
    return ?
```

Please Help me...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert time format into milliseconds and back in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5531249/how-to-convert-time-format-into-milliseconds-and-back-in-python)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41635547/7758804

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this

```py
import datetime

def past(h,m,s):
    return datetime.timedelta(hours=h, minutes=m, seconds=s).total_seconds()*1000
```

This will convert the timedelta object into seconds and then multiply it by a 1000 to get the milliseconds.

Alternatively you could just use maths

```
def past(h,m,s):
    returns (h*(60**2)+m*60+s)*1000
```

Which is equal to `(hours*seconds_in_hour + minutes*seconds_in_minutes + seconds) * millis_in_second`

Answer (score 0):

1 hour = 3600000 ms 
1 minute = 60000 ms 
1 second = 1000 ms 
then the equation would be

```
ms = (h*3600000) + (m*60000) + (s*1000)
```

here is the function

```
def past(h,m,s):
    return ((h*3600000) + (m*60000) + (s*1000))
```